# Optimize MySQL query with ORDER BY and INNER JOIN (select where user following)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I need to optimize the following query:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM Activity AS a
  JOIN users_following AS f1 
    ON f1.userId = a.originatorId 
   AND f1.followerId = 1 
 ORDER 
    BY a.time DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

The idea is to get all activity originated by users some user (in this case, user 1) is following, sorted by time. This query as written is very slow (~5s), though it's very quick if either a) the join is omitted or b) the order by clause is omitted.

Things I've tried:

- `WHERE ... IN` as opposed to `INNER JOIN`

Here are the CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE `Activity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `voteId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commentId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `achievementId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `challengeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followerId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acknowledged` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `isPrivate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `portalId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `portalMemberId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `originatorId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_55026B0C1CC880D8` (`portalMemberId`),
  KEY `IDX_55026B0C1D79C36A` (`challengeId`),
  KEY `IDX_55026B0CE7A069D0` (`achievementId`),
  KEY `IDX_55026B0CB6FEC0EE` (`voteId`),
  KEY `IDX_55026B0C6690C3F5` (`commentId`),
  KEY `IDX_55026B0C64B64DCC` (`userId`),
  KEY `IDX_55026B0CF542AA03` (`followerId`),
  KEY `IDX_55026B0C57076B1F` (`portalId`),
  KEY `IDX_55026B0CE094D20D` (`postId`),
  KEY `IDX_55026B0C162E014D` (`originatorId`),
  KEY `activity_time_idx` (`time`),
  KEY `activity_filter_idx` (`type`,`originatorId`,`userId`,`isPrivate`),
  KEY `acknowledged_idx` (`acknowledged`),
  KEY `idx1` (`time`,`originatorId`),
  KEY `idx2` (`originatorId`,`userId`,`postId`,`challengeId`,`commentId`,`time`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0C162E014D` FOREIGN KEY (`originatorId`) REFERENCES `ProseUser` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0C1CC880D8` FOREIGN KEY (`portalMemberId`) REFERENCES `PortalMember` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0C1D79C36A` FOREIGN KEY (`challengeId`) REFERENCES `Challenge` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0C57076B1F` FOREIGN KEY (`portalId`) REFERENCES `Portal` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0C64B64DCC` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `ProseUser` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0C6690C3F5` FOREIGN KEY (`commentId`) REFERENCES `Comment` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0CB6FEC0EE` FOREIGN KEY (`voteId`) REFERENCES `Vote` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0CE094D20D` FOREIGN KEY (`postId`) REFERENCES `Post` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0CE7A069D0` FOREIGN KEY (`achievementId`) REFERENCES `UserAchievement` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_55026B0CF542AA03` FOREIGN KEY (`followerId`) REFERENCES `ProseUser` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4097200 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;

CREATE TABLE `users_following` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `followerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`followerId`),
  KEY `IDX_17C2F70264B64DCC` (`userId`),
  KEY `IDX_17C2F702F542AA03` (`followerId`),
  KEY `idx1` (`userId`,`followerId`),
  KEY `idx2` (`followerId`,`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_17C2F70264B64DCC` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `ProseUser` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_17C2F702F542AA03` FOREIGN KEY (`followerId`) REFERENCES `ProseUser` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                               | key                  | key_len | ref                       | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f1    | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IDX_17C2F70264B64DCC,IDX_17C2F702F542AA03,idx1,idx2 | IDX_17C2F702F542AA03 | 4       | const                     |  145 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | ref  | IDX_55026B0C162E014D,idx2                                   | IDX_55026B0C162E014D | 5       | prose_2_24_2021.f1.userId |   38 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Get rid of the following: KEY `IDX_17C2F70264B64DCC` (`userId`),
  KEY `IDX_17C2F702F542AA03` (`followerId`),
  KEY `idx1` (`userId`,`followerId`),

Answer (score 0):

Let's make an example: user #1 follows users #2 and #3. Here are activities ordered by users, then time:

```
+------+-------+
| user | time  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | 10:00 |
|    1 | 11:00 |
|    2 | 10:00 |
|    2 | 12:00 |
|    3 | 09:00 |
|    3 | 13:00 |
|    4 | 10:00 |
+------+-------+
```

We can quickly find the followed users' activities, but get the times unordered:

```
+------+-------+
| user | time  |
+------+-------+
|    2 | 10:00 |
|    2 | 12:00 |
|    3 | 09:00 |
|    3 | 13:00 |
+------+-------+
```

This means that we must sort them in order to get the top n sorted. And if these were not four but thousands or millions of activities that would take awfully long.

If on the other hand the data were available ordered by time descending, then user:

```
+------+-------+
| user | time  |
+------+-------+
|    3 | 13:00 |
|    2 | 12:00 |
|    1 | 11:00 |
|    1 | 10:00 |
|    2 | 10:00 |
|    4 | 10:00 |
|    3 | 09:00 |
+------+-------+
```

We would have to read the whole data sequentially until we found the n top activities. No further ordering necessary. If we are lucky the first n rows are matches and that's it. If we are unlucky we read the whole table (or index for that matter).

So, there is no guarantee to get this quick. The first approach gets the data quick, but sorting can take long. The second approach needs no sorting, but reading can take long.

I like the second approach a tad better, but it all depends on the data of course. Are there many users? Is the majority followed by user #1 or only few? Are there many activities? Many by few users or few activities per user? ... Anyway, I'd provide this index:

```
create index idx1 on activity (time desc, originatorid);
```

As an index is just an offer to the DBMS we might just as well provide the other index for the case the DBMS wants to follow the other route:

```
create index idx2 on activity (originatorid, time desc);
```

And this is how I'd probably write the query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM activity AS a
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM users_following AS f1 
  WHERE f1.userId = a.originatorId 
  AND f1.followerId = 1 
)
ORDER BY a.time DESC
LIMIT 10;
```